# How to repeatedly read a file from the last location

Tags: python, file, file-io

I am trying to read a syslog repeatedly and only start from the point I left off last read.  I am trying to save the location of tell() is a sperate file and reload to seek before every read.

```
    lf = open("location.file", 'r')
    s = lf.readline()
    last_pos = int(s.strip())
    lf.close()

    sl = open("/var/log/messages", 'r')
    sl.seek(last_pos)
    for line in sl.readlines():
         # This should be the starting point from the last read
    last_loc = sl.tell()

    lf = open("location.file", "w+")
    lf.write(last_loc)
    lf.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write `str(last_loc)` instead of `last_loc`.

   The rest are probably optional.
2. Use `w` instead of `w+` for writing the location.
3. Close `/var/log/messages` when you're done with it.
4. Depending on your version of Python (definitely on 2.6 or newer, maybe on 2.5 depending), you may want to use `with` to automatially close files.
5. You probably don't need `strip` if you're just writing the value.
6. You can just use `read` instead of `readline` on `lf`.
7. You can iterate over the file itself, rather than using `readlines`, for `sl`.

   ```
   try:
       with open("location.file") as lf:
           s = lf.read()
           last_pos = int(s)
   except:
       last_post = 0

   with open("/var/log/messages") as sl:
       sl.seek(last_pos)
       for line in sl:
           # This should be the starting point from the last read
       last_loc = sl.tell()

   with open("location.file", "w") as lf:
       lf.write(str(last_loc))
   ```

Comment: <code>
try:
 with open("location.file") as lf:
  s = lf.read()
  last_pos = int(s)
except:
  last_pos = 0;
</code>

Comment: You have to use backticks in comments, but otherwise, good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your readline is weird.  What you nee to do is either:

1) save the value as a string and parse it:

```
lf.write(str(last_loc))
```

2) save and reread the location as an int:

```
lf.write(struct.pack("Q",lf.tell()))
last_pos = struct.unpack("Q",lf.read())
```

Comment: Still didn't show him how to actually write the int to the file :)